# How many times do I roll an unfair die to determine its bias?

Tags: probability, dice

This question comes from computer security, but I'll distill it into a probability question:

I have a biased die with 96 sides.  95 sides are equiprobable, each having a 1% chance of landing up.  The remaining side, side X, has a 5% chance.

All sides **look** identical; I want to identify side X.  My best strategy is obviously to roll it a bunch of times and take the majority, but my question is this: how many rolls are needed until Pr{X is majority result} > p for any given p > 1/2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a way to approximate the answer using information theory. Let $X$ be the variable representing the side, and let $D$ be an outcome of a roll. Each roll tells you that much information about $X$:
$$ I(X;D) = H(D) - H(D|X) = \log 96 + 95 \cdot 0.01 \log 0.01 + 0.05 \log 0.05. $$
As an approximation, the information gained from different rolls is additive; it's certainly at most additive. Since $H(X) = \log 96$ (since you have no a-priori belief about $X$), the number of rolls needed is at least
$$ \frac{H(X)}{I(X;D)} \approx 115. $$

---

Another way to approach the same question is as follows. Suppose the die was thrown $N$ times. The good side came up approximately $N/20$ times, and all the others came up $\mathrm{Bin}(N,0.01) \approx \mathcal{N}(0.01N,0.0099N)$. So we want the probability that such a normal variable be larger than $N/20$ to be smaller than $1/95$ (since there are $95$ such variables; we're ignoring their dependence). This is $$\frac{0.05N - 0.01N}{\sqrt{0.0099N}} \approx 0.4\sqrt{N}$$ standard deviations. Looking at a table, we need roughly $2.3$ standard deviations to get a probability of $1/95$, so we need $$N \approx (2.3/0.4)^2 = 33. $$ Of course, this estimate is pretty rough (it doesn't even match our previous supposed lower bound).

---

The estimate in the previous paragraph is particularly problematic since in this range the convergence to the normal distribution is pretty bad (the expectation is very small, roughly $1$). In this regime, the probability is actually roughly Poissonian. Let's estimate the probability of success when $N=100$ using this approximation. The correct side is going to show up roughly $5$ times. Each other side is going to show up $P(1)$ times, so it's going to be as large as $4$ with probability
$$ 1 - e^{-1} \sum_{t=0}^4 \frac{1^t}{t!} \approx 0.00366. $$
So the expected number of "contenders" is
$$ 0.00366 \cdot 95 \approx 0.35.$$
Assuming independence, the probability of no contenders is roughly
$$ (1 - 0.00366)^{95} \approx 0.706. $$
This approximation is only roughly vindicated by the experiments below.

In order to find a better approximation, let's take into account the roughly $P(5)$ distribution of the histogram of $X$:
$$ e^{-5} \sum_{H=0}^\infty \frac{5^H}{H!} \left(e^{-1} \sum_{t=0}^{H-1} \frac{1}{t!} \right)^{95} \approx 0.527. $$
This conforms much better to the results below.

---

Finally, here are experimental results from one million trials, along with the Poisson approximation:

$$ \begin{array}{r|c|c}
N & \text{Experiment} & \text{Approx} \\\hline
50 & 0.272323 & 0.274900 \\
100 & 0.526765 & 0.527424 \\
150 & 0.718004 & 0.714956 \\
200 & 0.840143 & 0.836808 \\
250 & 0.912917 & 0.910115 \\
300 & 0.954097 & 0.951953
\end{array}$$

The results support the information-theoretic bound, as well as our estimates obtained using the Poisson approximation.

Note: When the success probability is $p$ and there are $T$ trials, the standard deviation is $$\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{T}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{T}}.$$ In our case, $T = 10^6$ and so a standard deviation is at most $0.5\cdot 10^{-3}$. With probability $95\%$, the error is at most two standard deviations, i.e. $\pm 0.001$. So the experimental results are correct up to roughly the third digit (which may be slightly off itself).

Answer (score 6):

As the other answer shows, the answer is not simple. This is because it depends on the exact sequence of rolls. You can see this using Bayesian reasoning. Let $X$ be a r.v. that indicates the biased side. Denote the value of the $i^\mathrm{th}$ role by $Y_i$. Then,

$$p(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n|X=x) =  \left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^{m_x} \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^{n-m_x}$$

where

$$m_x = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{1}\left(Y_i = x\right)$$

and $\mathbf{1}$ is the indicator function. Then, we can use Bayes rule to calculate the probability of $X=x$ given a sequence of rolls.

$$p(X=x|Y_1, \cdots, Y_n) = \frac{p(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n|X=x)p(X=x)}{P(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n)} = \frac{p(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n|X=x)p(X=x)}{\sum_{x'} P(Y_1, \cdots, Y_n | X=x')p(X=x')}$$

Substituting from above and assuming all sides are uniformly equal

$$=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^{m_x} \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^{n-m_x} \frac{1}{96}}{\sum_{x'=1}^{96}\left[ \left(\frac{1}{20}\right)^{m_{x'}} \left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^{n-m_{x'}}\right] \frac{1}{96}}$$

So, basically, its hard to know a priori how many rolls because it depends on how many "repeats" on all sides comes up. But, you can easily compute the probability that $X=x$ where $x$ is any side you want and stop after enough rolls.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of this simple approach, which is sufficient for my needs: I just want to know when I can stop rolling the die and this (adaptive) method works great.  I didn't need to phrase my question as requiring the number of rolls up front.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Let's agree that the first side has $5\%$ chance, and remaining $95$ sides each have $1\%$ of occurrence. After $n$ rolls, let $N_k$ denote the random variable for the number of occurrences of $k$-th side. Then the random vector $(N_1,\ldots, N_{96})$, subject to $\sum_{k=1}^{96} N_k = n$, follows multi-nomial distribution.

I would interpret your question as a quest to determine, for $p > \frac{1}{2}$:
$$
  n_\mathrm{min} = \operatorname{arg min}_n \mathbb{P}(N_1 > N_2 \land N_1 > N_3 \land \ldots \land N_1 > N_{96} ) > p
$$

This probability equals:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \mathbb{P}\left( \land_{k=2}^{96} N_1 > N_k \right) &=& \sum_{n_1=1}^n \mathbb{P}\left( \land_{k=2}^{96}  N_k \le n_1 -1 ; N_1 = n_1 \right) \mathbb{P}\left( N_1 = n_1 \right) \\
   &=& \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left( F\left( k+1,k,\ldots,k \right) - F\left( k,k,\ldots,k \right) \right)
  \end{eqnarray}
$$
where $F(n_1,\ldots,n_k,\ldots,n_{96}) = \mathbb{P}\left( N_1 \le n_1, \ldots, N_k \le n_k,\ldots, N_{96} \le n_{96} \right)$.

Even when normal or Poisson approximation to multinomial cumulative distribution function is applicable, it does not simplify matter very much.

As an approximation $F$ can be replaced with product of marginal cumulative distribution functions, since correlation coefficients are on the order of $0.01$, i.e. small:
$$
   \mathbb{P}\left( \land_{k=2}^{96} N_1 > N_k \right) = 
      \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} f_{\mathrm{Bi}\left(n, \frac{1}{20}\right)}(k+1) \left( F_{\mathrm{Bi}\left(n, \frac{1}{95}\right)}(k) \right)^{95}
$$

I ran simulation, and plotted the probability $\mathbb{P}(\land_{k=2}^{96} N_k < N_1)$ as a function of $n$, and compared to this approximation, the agreement is rather good:

[image]